# Compute the expected number of dice that have been rolled at least once.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have been stuck forever on a homework problem. I thought I found the solution to the problem, but a friend simulated the setup with code and got a different final answer. I'm pretty sure his code is correct, but I also don't understand what could be wrong about my answer, so I was hoping you could enlighten me!

**Problem Definition:** You have in total 5 dice. You select one of them at random and roll it. Then, you repeat this procedure 8 more times. Compute the expected number of dice that have been rolled at least once.

**My Solution:** We can ignore the order of how we threw the dice. The total number of possibilities is
\begin{equation}
  N={9+5-1 \choose 9}={13 \choose 9}=715.
\end{equation}
For exactly $x$ different dice thrown at least once, we know that there are ${5 \choose x}$ amount of ways we can choose *which* dice to throw at least once. For each possible choice we for sure throw all $x$ dice once, after that we are free to do $9-x$ more throws. Every throw we get to choose any of the $x$ dice, thus
\begin{equation}
  n(x)={5 \choose x}{(9-x)+x-1 \choose 9-x}={5 \choose x}{8 \choose 9-x},
\end{equation}
where $n(x)$ is the amount of ways we could have thrown exactly $x$ dice at least once.

For the last step we just use a calculator, giving:
\begin{equation}
  \mathbb{E}(X)=\sum_{x=1}^5x\, \frac{n(x)}{N}=\frac{45}{13}.
\end{equation}

Comment: I can't follow your computation.  You appear to be using Stars and Bars, but that's not relevant here (as the Stars and Bars solutions are not equally probable).  I have posted an alternate calculation below.

Comment: As @lulu remarks, stars and bars is inappropriate.  Surely it's more likely that the first $4$ dice are each rolled twice and the last one once than that the first one is rolled $9$ times.

Comment: @lulu I see your answer, thank you. I feel incredibly dumb not coming up with it myself because it's so simple, but that's math sometimes I guess. I don't understand what do you mean with that the Stars and Bars solutions are not equally probable?

Comment: Read my comment just before yours.

Comment: Thisis a common misunderstanding.  If you are putting two identical balls in two distinct urns the Stars and Bars patterns are $(2,0), (1,1), (0,2)$.  And indeed $\binom 31=3$.  But if each ball can go into each urn with equal probability the probabilities of these three patterns are $\frac 14, \frac 12, \frac 14$.  Not equal.

Comment: Ah okay, I think I understand now! Thanks very much @lulu (and @saulspatz), I was stuck on this problem for forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:  Stars and Bars can't easily be applied here as the different patterns counted by this method are not equally probable.  As a general statement, it is more likely that you'll see each die equally often as that you'll see one specified die much more than the others.

To compute the expected number:

We use indicator variables.  The probability that a die is never rolled is $\left(\frac 45\right)^9$.  Thus the probability that a die is rolled at least once is $$1-\left(\frac 45\right)^9$$.

As there are $5$ dice the answer is then $$5\times \left(1-\left(\frac 45\right)^9\right)=4.32891136$$